# Distorted site after deployment on Netlify

Tags: css, reactjs, github, deployment, netlify

I deployed my React project on netlify which on my pc displays as is supposed but after deploying it and accessing the deployed site, the page is distorted.

This is how it is supposed to look: [image]

But this is how it looks: [image: Image after being deployed]

I feel the problem is related to my CSS but i don't know how or where.

This is the link to the project repo on Github: [project repo](https://github.com/create2000/E-comm)

Comment: Have you checked the network tab? It looks like your images have wrong path